# Action at a distance, how does unitary operator changes the state?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information

Alice and Bob share a state (dropped the normalization constant) $|\phi\rangle=\sum_i|ii\rangle$.Now Alice applies a unitary operator $U$ to her qubit, and Bob does nothing.

Now the following is from my notebook:

$$|\phi\rangle=U\otimes I\sum_i|ii\rangle=\sum_i\sum_j |j \rangle  \langle j |U|i\rangle|i\rangle= \sum_i\sum_j |j \rangle  |i\rangle\langle j |U|i\rangle=\sum_i\sum_j |j \rangle  |i\rangle\langle i |U^T|j\rangle=\sum_j |j \rangle U^T|j \rangle $$

I don't understand why it is $U^T$ and not $U^\dagger$.

What subchapter of Nielsen & Chuang or Preskill should I read?

Comment: $\langle j | U | i \rangle = U_{ji} = (U^T)_{ij} = \langle i | U^T | j \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$|\phi\rangle=U\otimes I\sum_i|ii\rangle=\sum_i\sum_j |j \rangle  \langle j |U|i\rangle|i\rangle= \sum_i\sum_j |j \rangle  |i\rangle\langle j |U|i\rangle=\sum_i\sum_j |j \rangle  |i\rangle\langle i |U^T|j\rangle=\sum_j |j \rangle U^T|j \rangle $$

> I don't understand why it is $U^T$ and not $U^\dagger$.

It looks like you are supposed to use the definition of the transpose of a matrix, and also to forgive the abuse of notation wherein an operator and a matrix are somewhat confused.

By definition, the matrix elements of the transpose of a matrix $M$ are:
$$
{M}^{T}_{ij} = M_{ji}
$$

By definition, the matrix elements of the Hermitian conjugate of a matrix $M$ are:
$$
{M}^{\dagger}_{ij} = M_{ji}^*
$$

Your matrix elements (numbers) are defined as:
$$
U_{ij} = \langle i|\hat U|j \rangle\;,
$$
where I've put a little hat on the operator $\hat U$ to differentiate it from the matrix $U$ ($U_{ij}$ are numbers).

Apparently we are supposed to understand that:
$$
\langle i| \hat U^T | j \rangle
$$
means:
$$
U^T_{ij}\;.
$$

So, then by using these definitions (and dropping the "hat")
$$
\langle i | U^T |j\rangle = U^T_{ij} = U_{ji} = \langle j | U |i\rangle\;.
$$